# Reload Components when change in Props in VueJS

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue.js

I'm using the following code to show a component which passes a value 'category'. The category changes based on user interactions. However, once a component is loaded, its data is not changed according to the change of props.

```
<button @click="selected='new'">Change</button>
<popup :category="selected"></popup>

data() {
    return {
      selected: 'test'
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will have to put a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on `category`  in  `popup` component, like following:

```
watch: {
  category: function(newVal){
    this.selected = newVal   // or this.openPopup(newVal) is this suits
  }
}
```

Comment: No, the openPop function is called when a button is clicked

Comment: How are you passing `category` to it, is watcher helping?

Comment: @GijoVarghese Yes, you have to add this watch in the `popup` component, if it does not work, can you add code of  `popup` component as well.

Comment: oh, that code is inside component right, let me try it